# How do I keep a program alive with timers?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a program that its' only action is calling a function every 24 hours. Obviously, I've been trying to use timers for that cause. However the program ends before the function is called for the first time (because the main thread ends first). Is there a way of keeping a program alive just with timers?

Comment: Make it a scheduled task?

Comment: Just turn this around.  Specify the reason a program should exit.  Implement it and you have little to fear from timers.

Answer (score 6):

Don't keep the program running for 24h, use a scheduled task at the wanted time and execute the program then.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a program to continually run on Windows and do something at a certain time.. write a service. Here's a tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3938/Creating-a-C-Service-Step-by-Step-Lesson-I

Comment: A service was my first thought actually. But I'm using VS12 and I've been having difficulties installing it.